# Sort 2D JavaScript array alphabetically and based on date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've got a nested array that I want to sort by the values in the inner array.
First sort by name alphabetically and next by date (from oldest to newest).

Let's say we have this array:

```
[['BBB','2020-10-20'],['AAA','2020-10-25'],['BBB','2020-10-19'],['EEE','2020-11-19'],['AAA','2020-10-10']]
```

After sorting it would look like this:

```
[['AAA','2020-10-10'],['AAA','2020-10-25'],['BBB','2020-10-19'],['BBB','2020-10-20'],['EEE','2020-11-19']]
```

Is it possible to do this with the `sort()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution:

You can sort both based on the first and second column in one line of code.

You just need to do a sorting for strings and date objects:

```js
var myArray  = 
[['BBB','2020-10-20'],
['AAA','2020-10-25'],
['BBB','2020-10-19'],
['EEE','2020-11-19'],
['AAA','2020-10-10']];

 myArray.sort( (a,b) => a[0].charCodeAt(0)-b[0].charCodeAt(0) || new Date(a[1]) - new Date(b[1]));

console.log(myArray);
```